# Attempting to access 2d array as a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am currently attempting to iterate through a 2d array to a function using pointer notation as an exercise.  I found an example of how to do this on these forums;  it's the if statement within the displayTable function.  My compiler is giving me errors about the function call itself stating that the if statement from the displayTable function must be of a pointer type.  Why is this not working?  The example was up voted.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    const int numRow = 6;
    const int numCol = 26;

    char letters[numRow][numCol] = {

        { 'm', 'w', 'r', 'u', 't', 'v', 'n', 'j', 'd', 'j', 'y', 'k', 'k', 'g', 'g', 'd', 'c', 'v', 'n', 'x', 'm', 'd', 'q', 'y', 'u', 't' },
        { 'y', 'e', 'r', 'y', 'e', 't', 'w', 'y', 'u', 'w', 'r', 's', 'f', 'h', 's', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'g', 'x', 'z' },
        { 'j', 'd', 'j', 'y', 'k', 'k', 'g', 'g', 'd', 'c', 'v', 'n', 't', 'w', 'y', 'u', 'w', 'r', 's', 'f', 'h', 's', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'g' },
        { 'y', 'e', 't', 'w', 'y', 'u', 'w', 'r', 's', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'y', 'k', 'k', 'g', 'g', 'd', 'c', 'v', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'd', 'b' },
        { 'e', 'r', 'y', 'e', 't', 't', 'v', 'n', 'j', 'd', 'j', 'y', 'k', 'w', 'r', 's', 'f', 'h', 's', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'd', 'c', 'v', 'g' },
        { 'y', 'u', 'w', 'r', 's', 'f', 'h', 's', 'g', 's', 'f', 'h', 's', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'd', 'w', 'y', 'u', 'w', 'r', 's', 'f', 'h' }
    };

    void displayTable(char[][26]);

    int main()
    {

        char *ltrptr = 0;
        ltrptr = &letters[0][0];
        const int arraySize = 6 * 26;
        int answer = 0;
        char * arr[6][26];

        displayTable(letters);

        getchar();
        return 0;

    }



    void displayTable(char ans[][26]){
        //pas 2d array, then point to it
        cout << " The table as it stands: " << endl;

        char * ans1;
        ans1 = &ans[0][0];

        for (char * iter = &ans1[0][0]; iter != &ans1[0][0] + 6 * 26; iter++){
            cout << &ans1[0][0] << endl;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `ans1` is a simple pointer-to-char and you're trying to dereference it twice. The correct way to do the loop would be

```
    for (char * iter = ans1; iter != ans1 + 6 * 26; iter++){
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }
```

Comment: interesting.  Thank you, that compiles.

Comment: @ChrisSamson Great. Don't forget to accept my answer ;)

Comment: `void displayTable(char ans[][26]){
 //pas 2d array, then point to it
 cout << " The table as it stands: " << endl;





 for(char * iter = &ans[0][0]; iter != &ans[0][0] + 6 * 26; iter++){
  cout << *iter << endl;
 }
}`  That's eventually what I went with, as I needed the index but it doesn't really matter I suppose since it's the same mem location.